# Function on helper.php not detected with codeception Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, codeception

I'm making function test on my laravel(4) project with Codeception. But it doesn't detected function define in Laravel helper.php file. If anybody know please let me know the way to fix it. Thanks.

```
function rangeWithKeys($from, $to, $leadingZeros = false)
{

    if ($leadingZeros === TRUE )
    {
        $array = [];

        for($i =$from; $i <= $to; $i++)
        {
            if($i<10){
                $prefixedNumber = '0'.$i;
                $array[$prefixedNumber] = $prefixedNumber;
            }else{
                $array[$i] = $i;
            }
        }

        return $array;

    }

    $array = array_combine(range($from,$to),range($from,$to));

    return $array;
}
```

I use this helper function for form select but when run codeception, got Call to undefined function **rangeWithKeys()** error.

```
{{ Form::select('birthMonth', array('M' => 'M') + rangeWithKeys(1,12, TRUE), Input::old('Month') ? Input::old('Month') : 'M',['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the following syntax in top of the controller file.

```
use <helper class name>;
```

Comment: Yeah, i was try it again add helper class in top of controller but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's work when i added **require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';** in _boostrap.php under codeception test folder.